# MySql - get the opposite of the column from my answer

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have database with 3 columns: `id`, `numbers1` and `numbers2`.

I am doing a query like this:

```
select id from numbers where numbers.numbers1 = numbers.numbers2;
```

And I am getting a result of something in the id column.

Assuming I have `1,2,3,4,5` in the `id` column and I am getting as a result 1,2,3 how do i show what have left from the column? I mean how do I show in the result 4,5? and not the 1,2,3 that I got in the result?

Comment: Too hard to figure this out `select id from numbers where numbers.numbers1 <> numbers.numbers2;` ? What can be opposite to `EQUAL`? May be `NOT EQUAL`?

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't help me because there are a lot of values in those columns and i am getting a lot more answers from what i need. actually i need to do this query but instead of getting the original result i need to get "the entire column (id) less then the original result. here is 1,2,3,4,5 less then 1,2,3 (the result of the query) so the result will be 4,5.

Comment: @Danny, your last comment does not make sense to me.

Comment: sorry for the ignorance, i am little bit new in this field. what didn't you understand? i have an `id` column which i am getting in the result `1,2,3` for the `id` column. what i want to do is not showing in the result the `1,2,3`. i want to show the `4,5` meaning the entire column `id` less the original `1,2,3` result.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to just query the opposite - instead of `=`, using `!=`:

```
SELECT id
FROM   numbers
WHERE  numbers.numbers1 != numbers.numbers2;
```

Comment: seems that i am getting more results of what i need.